# Linear Least Squares with Monotonicity Constraint

Tags: least-squares, linear-regression

I'm interested in the multidimensional linear least squares problem: $$\min_{x}||Ax-b||^2$$
subject to a monotonicity constraint for $x$, meaning that the elements of $x$ are monotonically increasing: $x_0 \leq x_1$, $x_1 \leq x_2$, ... , $x_{n-1} \leq x_n$.

I basically have two questions regarding this problem:

1.) Is there maybe literature regarding this problem out there? I wasn't able to find anything online so far.

2.) If not, is it maybe possible to rewrite my problem in such a way that i could use already existing methods like Non Negative Least Squares (NNLS) or a Constrained Least Squares (CLS) method?

Regarding the NNLS, I had the idea to formulate my problem in terms of an $\tilde{x} := (x_0, x_1-x_0,\; ...\;,x_n - x_{n-1})$ as this would also achieve monotonicity if every term in non negative, but I can't seem to do it, maybe I'm missing something here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [Isotonic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression), maybee it will help.

Comment: Unfortunately Isotonic regression tackles another kind of problem. I'm not trying to fit a monotonic line through data, but rather want my parameters which i solve for in the linear regression to be monotonic.

Comment: Do you want a theoretical-type answer or a practical way to try to compute a solution? I assume it's the second?

Comment: I would be happy with either actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L$ be an $n\times n+1$ matrix such that $$ L = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 & ... &0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & ... &0 \\
 &  &               \\
0  & 0 & ...& -1 &1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then you can formulate this as a constrained least squares problem$$\min_{x}||Ax-b||^2\ s.t. Lx \geq 0$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That would certainly work. I was kinda hoping to avoid such a reformulation as an inequality CLS problem as it might be a little bit numerically unstable with high dimensionality, but I guess to easiest way to solve this kind of problem would be using CVX?

Comment: I am not an expert on numerical optimization but this should be a pretty standard problem. E.g. Matlab has a command lsqlin for CLS.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea to reformulate the problem so that the variables are $x_0$ and $y_i = x_i - x_{i-1}$ for $i =1, \ldots, n$ will work. Let $y$ be the vector whose components are $x_0, y_1, \ldots, y_n$ and
define
$$
M = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & & & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 
\end{bmatrix}}_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}.
$$

Notice that $M y = x$. Expressed in terms of $y$, your optimization problem is to minimize $\| AM y - b \|^2$ subject to the constraint that $y_i \geq 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. In this reformulated problem, the optimization variable is the vector $y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe you misunderstood my problem a little bit, though your suggestion will still work if i define $y_i=x_i - x_{i-1}$ and then fill the Matrix M with 1s for every element left of the diagonal.

Comment: @Anton Thanks, I think I fixed my answer now.

Comment: Yes you did, that definitely works. Thanks!